# Enforcing a set of keys in one part of the json to subset a set of keys in another part of the json using a json schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm working on a json schema that defines a family of jsons and there's a certain constraint I'm not sure how to enforce. In a valid json file I'm supposed to have (among other things) two objects. Let's call the first object `entities` and the second object `fields`. The `entities` object also contains an `entityFields` entry which should contain objects whose keys come from the set of keys in `fields`. To make the description clear, I'll demonstrate it using the following valid json:

```
{
  "entities":
  {
    "entity1":
    {
      "entityFields":
      {
        "field1": {},
        "field2": {}
      }
    },
    "entity2":
    {
      "entityFields":
      {
        "field4": {},
        "field5": {}
      }
    },
    "entity3":
    {
      "entityFields":
      {
        "field1": {},
        "field5": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "fields":
  {
    "field1": {},
    "field2": {},
    "field3": {},
    "field4": {},
    "field5": {},
    "field6": {}
  }
}
```

Observe that each entity has entity fields coming from the set of fields defined below under `fields`. This is the constraint I'm trying to enforce. In general, how do I enforce the set of keys in one part of my json to be a subset of the set of keys in a different part of the json? Specifically, what should I add to the json schema in order to require this from the set of valid jsons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely no way to carry this out with json schema.

You have the following options:

- perform the validation manually, without any json schema
- first traverse your `entities` and `entityFields`, programmatically generate a json schema from these, then validate the fields against the generated schema. The `entities` and `entityFields` form some naive type system - in this concept, you may want to translate these to an other type system (json schema).